# Problem with .Net Encoding namespace?

Tags: .net, encoding

I've just encountered an issue while trying to write a small encryption DLL for our company (the first time I've had to do such a thing) .

If I use the following code to get the byte[] out of a string (in my case a British pound sign £), and then use the same area of the .Net Framework to get the char[] for the byte[] I get a question mark instead of the expected £!

Can anyone explaiom to me why this is?

byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("£");
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(asciiBytes).ToString());

Comment: GetChars returns char[] right? Does char[].ToString() even do anything sensible? `new string(char[])` would look more likely, or GetString...?

Comment: Note on the title of your question: Encoding is a class, not a namespace.

Comment: I used to have a prehistoric English design that had a character ROM and keyboard that replaced $ with £.  The company didn't last long enough to set any kind of standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use the ASCII encoding, but the pound sign isn't in ASCII. The encoding can't deal with the character, so it's using the encoded form of "?" as an indicator that something's wrong.

I suggest you use UTF-8 instead. All Unicode characters can be represented in UTF-8, and it's efficient for genuinely ASCII strings (which are very common).

One thing to be aware of: encryption generally works on arbitrary binary data and the *result* is arbitrary binary data. **Do not** try to convert the results of encryption back to a string using something like `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)` - that will lead to data loss as the arbitrary binary data almost certainly won't be a valid UTF-8-encoded sequence of characters. If you need a string result, use base64 encoding: `Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)`.